# How do I add reCAPTCHA to my registerviewmodel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, recaptcha

Following the documentation [here](http://recaptchamvc.apphb.com/), I was able to install the tool, add it in my account controller:

```
using reCAPTCHA.MVC;
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, bool captchaValid)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //do some stuff     
        if (captchaValid)
        {
            //do some stuff
        }
     }
}
```

and add it to my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Recaptcha()
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.ValidationMessage("ReCaptcha")
    </div>
</div>
```

However, the documentation does not tell you how to add it to the `RegisterViewModel` which mine currently looks like this:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public bool Recapcha { get; set; }
}
```

Using this gives me the error: 
**System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper(ProjectName.Models.RegisterViewModel)' does not contain a definition for 'Recaptcha' and no extension method 'Recaptcha' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper(ProjectName.Models.RegisterViewModel)' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. That exception is saying that the `Html.Recaptcha` extension method you're trying to use does not exist. Either it's the wrong name for the extension provided by `reCAPTCHA.MVC`, or more likely, the view has no reference to that namespace. You can correct that by either:

1. Add a using statement to the top of your view:

   ```
   @using reCAPTCHA.MVC
   ```
2. Edit the `Web.config` file in your `Views` directory (not your main `Web.config`). Find the section like:

   ```
   <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
     <namespaces>
       <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
       <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
       <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
       <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
       <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
     </namespaces>
   </pages>
   ```

   And add an additional namespace reference there:

   ```
   <add namespace="reCAPTCHA.MVC" />
   ```

Comment: This worked like a charm when the public and private codes are added in 
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq